# How can I determine how many solutions an Initial Value Problem has?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In class, we worked on this differential equation

> $y'=\frac{2y}{x}$ with $y(x_0)=y_0$
>
> > We solved it and got $y=cx^2$

I have no problem with how we arrived to this general solution. However, the professor then explained that:

> If $x_0 \ne 0$ and $y_o \ne 0$ then $y(x)=\frac{y_0}{x_0}x^2$
>
> If $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0=0$ then $y(x) = cx^2$ for any $c \in \mathbb R$
>
> If $x_0=0$ and $y_0 \ne 0$ then we have no solutions

I am not really sure how he came this these conclusions. I can understand the first conclusion. And given these conclusions I can see that there would be an infinite amount of solutions or no solutions depending on the initial conditions, but are there any theorems that I am not aware of that would let me know that there are no solutions or an infinite amount of solutions out there?

I know the existence theorem; in short, given $y'=f(x,y)$ if $f(x,y)$ is continuous in some rectangle then there exists a region in that rectangle such that a solution exists.

But above, $\frac{2y}{x}$ is not continuous at $x=0$ so why does it have a solution (an infinite, that is) if $x_0=y_0=0$?

Comment: i.e. how do we know when there are no solutions and how do we know when there are infinite solutions?

Comment: Look up the existence and uniqueness theorem. It essentially states the following: Given an equation of the form $y'=f(x,y)$ with initial value $y(x_0)=y_0$, if $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on some rectangle $R$ (with $(x_0,y_0)$ an interior point of $R$), then the solution is unique.

Comment: This is just algebra. When you substitute $x=0$ and $y=0$ into the equation $y=cx^2$, you get $0=0$, which provides no information about $c$. If you substitute $x=0$ and $y=a\not=0$, then you get $a=c\cdot 0^2=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: To answer your other question, you will find a lot of theorems that say "If $X$ happens, then $Y$ happens." However, it is possible for $Y$ to happen without $X$ happening. Real life instance: If it rains, then the road gets wet. But the road can get wet if it doesn't rain; someone could have bad aim when they're watering their lawn, for instance.

Comment: If the hypotheses of the existence and uniqueness theorem aren't satisfied, it does not say that you do not have a unique solution. You must try to construct multiple solutions, or show why none exist. For instance, if as in your problem, $x_0=0$, $y_0\neq 0$, it's not possible to have a solution, as @CarlHeckman stated, but if $x_0=y_0=0$, this yields the (unhelpful) condition 0=0, meaning there is a different solution $y = cx^2$ for each real number $c$.